# "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://connect.facebo

Tags: unsafe-eval

Please help! I Googled this error message and it brought me here. Im not a programer developer anything. Should I just throw this laptop out?
thanks for any help

I googled the error code it brought me here.